# text file reduction with randomization in Python

Tags: python, parsing, text, random, reduction

I solved the following problem in bash, but I feel it's quite inefficient and very slow given the size of files I need to reduce. Was hoping somebody has an idea how to do the same in Python and hopefully speed things up.

The original problem was to reduce very large text files (50-60 million lines, tab delimited columns).
One of the columns is being treated as a key, i.e. we determine how many lines with a unique key are in the file and then randomly select a percentage of them (for example a quarter of total number if reducing by 75%) to append to a new file that will keep our results. We continue to go through the rest of the keys, randomizing and then reducing all lines containing each unique key by the same percentage. In case the reduction can't be done - we simply carry all the lines over to the resulting file.

As I said, my bash script works quite well, but it is slow and strings together various awk and grep constructs. By all accounts, Python should deal with this in a much more elegant way and without compromising memory too much (again, we are dealing with 50+ million lines files in this case).
Any suggestions/tricks would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: That's a pretty big file. Depending on how many unique keys you have, just taking 25% of all lines might give very similar results with far less work. Would this be an option, or do you need to ensure the ratio per key?

Comment: Can you sort the files by key, using OS tools?

Comment: Do you have enough RAM to read any of the files fully into memory? eg. using `mylist = open("filename").readlines()`

Comment: If you are handling a 60 million row database in a text file, you're doing it wrong. Use a real database manager, even SQLite. The cost of converting is minimal and the benefits in processing speed and data reliability can be enormous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution would be to sort a file by the key column e.g., [sort](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) tab-separated input by the second column:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "a\tz\nb\ty\nc\tx" | sort -k 2 -t $'\t'
```

And then solve a simpler problem of retrieving 25% of random lines for each unique key where all lines with equal keys are adjacent with a constraint that at least one line for each unique key should be preserved:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import sys
from itertools import chain, groupby

def choose_random(iterator, fraction, random=random.random):
    """Lazy analog of:

        L = list(iterator)
        k = int(len(L) * fraction + .5) or 1 # get at least one
        result = random.sample(L, k)

    Note: this function doesn't randomize the order of elements
          that would require to keep selected elements in memory
          and number of output elements is not exactly k
    """
    # always yield at least one item if input is not empty
    item = next(iterator)
    it = (x for x in chain([item], iterator) if random() < fraction)
    for x in chain([next(it, item)], it):
        yield x

def getkey(line):
    return line.split("\t")[1] # 2nd column

for key, group in groupby(sys.stdin, key=getkey):
    sys.stdout.writelines(choose_random(group, fraction=0.25))
```

Note: the last line in the input file should contain a newline otherwise the output is corrupted if the last line is chosen.

The script accepts sorted (by the key column) input on stdin and prints reduced output to stdout. It requires to store only one line in memory at a time. It is a single-pass algorithm (O(n)).

Comment: "We need you Sebastian. You're our best and only friend." ;) Thanks a bunch!! I've made some small mods to your script and it worked BEAUTIFULLY! Single-pass algorithms rule... I knew this thing can be done a lot faster with proper programming technique applied...

Answer (score 1):

Because your problem is vague, I will give a high level solution

1. Do not read the entire file in memory `fileObj.read()` or `fileObj.readlines()`, rather iterate through the file `for line in fileObj`. Why? This will be memory friednly
2. Create your implementation of Queue based on List

   ```
   class Queue(object):
       def __init__(self, max_size):
           self.queue = []
           self.max_size = max_size
       def __getitem__(self, index):
           if 0 <= index < max_size:
               return self.queue[index]
           else:
               raise IndexError
       def __iter__(self):
           return iter(self.queue)
       def push(seq):
           if isinstance(seq, Iterable):
               if len(self.queue) + len(seq) > self.max_size:
                   raise Full
               self.queue = seq
           else:
               if len(self.queue) + 1 > self.max_size:
                   raise Full
               self.queue.append(seq)
       def pop():
           if self.queue:
               return self.queue.pop(0)
   ```
3. Create a dictionary of Queue with a maxsize = 2 * percentage of selected items

Something like

```
    PCT_SELECTED = 100
    MAXSIZE = 2 * PCT_SELECTED
    KEY_START = 10
    KEY_STOP = 15 
    from collection import defaultdict
    queue_dict = defaultdict(Queue(MAXSIZE))
```

1. Put elements in the Queue in a non blocking fasion
2. If Queue is FULL, it will raise the Exception `Full`, in which case, you randomly select 50 % of elements from the Queue and discard the rest.

something like

```
    with open("your-file") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            key = line[KEY_START: KEY_STOP]
            try:
                queue_dict[key].push(line)
            except Full:
                queue_dict[key] = random.sample(queue_dict[key], PCT_SELECTED)
```

1. Finally iterate through the dictionary and trim out the Queue randomly

   ```
   queue_dict = {key: random.sample(value, PCT_SELECTED) for key, value in queue_dict.items()}
   ```
2. Now you can read through the dictinary and write to a file.

Comment: [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) has only one argument. Where does your `random.choice(value, PCT_SELECTED)` come from?

Answer (score 0):

For a large number of items just selecting 75% can be done by checking a random number for each one.

```
import random

with open('input') as f:
for line in f:
    if random.random() < 0.75:
        print line
```

And if you need to guarantee at least one item from each key (even if it only has two lines):

```
import random
keys = set()

with open('input') as f:
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split('\t')
        key = columns[0]

        if not key in keys:
           print line
           keys.add(key)
           continue

        if random.random() < 0.75:
            print line
```

Comment: You say this selects 75%, but `random.random() > 0.75` would select 25%.